# Htaccess rule to redirect domain to index.html

Tags: apache, unix, .htaccess, redirect, webserver

How do I write a rewrite-rule that redirects visitors to the domain `www.mydomain.com/` to `www.mydomain.com/index.html`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So you want to redirect *nothing* (`^$`) to `index.html`? That would then look like

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [L]
```

If you want to avoid *both* the `/` and `/index.html` being indexed by search bots, then add `R=301` to make it a [*permanent* redirect](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) rather than a [*temporary* redirect](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) (302, which is the default). This would let the bots only index the `/index.html`.

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: are there any effects on SEO by adding R=301 ?..... well it stop search engines to index the index.html page? if it does then it should not be added,

Comment: This is already explained in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

What **BalusC** said - but consider whether you really want to redirect them. Wouldn't it be better to just serve `index.html` when the browser requests `/`, like most servers do? It's an extra round-trip to the server for no gain and just makes the URL longer. It's so 1990s. :)

Comment: Seeing the context of the question (apache already does that by default) I rather think he just want to get rid of it :)

Comment: I wanted it for this reason: http://serverfault.com/questions/94706/how-to-password-protect-the-domain-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put your index.html in another folder, for exemple:
domain.com/welcome/index.html and do a R301 from your CPanel. 
It's a wordaround but it worked for me. Have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible there's a mistake above? It didn't work for me, redirecting me to a very long filepath *ending* in `/index.html`
The code that worked for me is:

```
# These two lines redirect the root to index.html.
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.html [R=301,L]
```

I found this solution at [.htaccess redirect root to index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175804/htaccess-redirect-root-to-index-php)