# .htaccess redirect root to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, root

I need to redirect from `http://example.com/` to `http://example.com/index.php`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use this:

```htaccess
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: For SEO reasons, it is _not_ ok to have the same content for two different URLs. So `DirectoryIndex` does _not_ help for the SEO scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Why do you need `mod_rewrite` for this ? `DirectoryIndex` is the correct answer here.

Comment: there's a difference in the way both work. default directory does not change the uri hence if you need to make some manipulations on it this is a mess.

Comment: For SEO reasons, it is _not_ ok to have the same content for two different URLs. So `DirectoryIndex` does _not_ help for the SEO scenario.

Comment: this solution is more flexible, since directory index cannot redirect as OP requested

Answer (score 2):

Just to add my own solution, since [the answer of Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10175840/107625) did not work for me, I did something like:

```htaccess
RewriteEngine on

# These two lines redirect non-www to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]

# These two lines redirect the root to index.html.
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.html [R=301,L]
```

This also preserves any possible existing query string parameters.

Comment: for me this line helped thank you `RewriteRule ^/$ /index.html [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [@Uwe Keim's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107625/uwe-keim) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51825547/8353776) above, I had non-www to www setup on Apache virtual hosts.

What worked for me on .htaccess was:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Two lines to redirect from the root web directory to myfile.html.
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.html [R=301,L]
```