# Redirect every request ending with slash (*/) to */index

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

There are so many pages on stackoverflow and elsewhere about Redirect. However, I couldn't find a solution to a simple problem: I want every request that ends with a slash to have a **permanent 301-redirect** to */index.

Examples:

> http://example.com/ - should redirect to http://example.com/index
>
> http://example.com/foo/ - should redirect to
> http://example.com/foo/index
>
> http://example.com/foo/bar/ - should redirect to
> http://example.com/foo/bar/index
>
> etc.

However, requests not ending with slash should not be redirected:

> http://example.com/foo - no redirect.
>
> http://example.com/foo/bar - no redirect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10175838/342740 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try and see how it works for you.

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ http://example.com/$1/index [R=302,L]
```

Change `[R=302,L]` to `[R=301,L]` when you're sure it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, this works _almost_. It redirects http://example.com/foo/ to http://example.com/var/www/foo/index ...

Comment: O.K., this works for me now: `RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ http://example.com/$1/index [R=302,L]` Do you wish to edit your answer so I can mark it as accepted answer?

Comment: Yes you could also use / in front of $1 to fix that also. Edited.