# Always show the directory index file with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

If this is my website and the user typed this url:

> http://mydomain.com/

How can I make it look like this every time someone visits the home page:

> http://mydomain.com/index.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911417/htaccess-rule-to-redirect-domain-to-index-html

Answer (score 3):

You can use `RedirectMatch` directive in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/?$ /index.php
```

OR using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php [L,R]
```